# Vertx event bus access_denied

Tags: javascript, java, vert.x

I have an java vertx server and a JavaScript client. I want to create an event bus under twice but vertx respond : Error received on connection: access_denied

Javascript code:

```
var eventBus = new vertx.EventBus("http://localhost:8989/eventbus");
eventBus.onopen = function () {
console.log("Event bus connected !");
console.log(eventBus);

eventBus.registerHandler("http://localhost:8989/eventbus/news-feed", function (message) {
    console.log("registred" + message.body());
});
```

Java code:

```
SockJSHandler bridge = SockJSHandler.create(vertx).bridge(new BridgeOptions());
router.route("/eventbus/*").handler(bridge);
router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create());// otherwise serve static pages
HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
httpServer.requestHandler(router::accept);
httpServer.listen(Servers.SERVER_PORT);
vertx.setPeriodic(1000, event -> {
vertx.eventBus().publish("news-feed", "{\"c\":\"df\"}");
```

Have you an idea?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

You need to set Permissions in the BridgeOptions:

```
BridgeOptions options = new BridgeOptions()
.addInboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddress("news-feed"))
.addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddress("news-feed"));
```

Also, your Javascript code can't sign up for the whole address:

```
eventBus.registerHandler("news-feed", ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddress("news-feed"));
```

is required ,and

```
 eb.registerHandler('news-feed', function(error, message) {
      console.log('received a message: ' + JSON.stringify(message));});
```

the callback function has two param is required